# Flipping array in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My original table looks like:

```
id, date, 1, 2, 3,
 1    1   10 10 10 
 1    2   20 20 20 
 1    3   30 30 30 
 1    4   15 15 15
```

By running the query:

```
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(1, 2, 3)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 
PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

I get this output

```
   1      2     3 
1  10    10     10
2  10    10     10
   20    20     20 
3  10    10     10 
   20    20     20  
   30    30     30 
4  20    20     20 
   30    30     30 
   15    15     15
```

I would like the output to be:

```
 1      2     3 
1  10    10     10
2  20    20     20
   10    10     10 
3  30    30     30 
   20    20     20  
   10    10     10
4  15    15     15 
   30    30     30 
   20    20     20
```

So bascically, the values that I get in my output are all correct, but I would like order of the output to be flipped. Anyone know how to do that with an array(struct)) type of column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to reverse the sort order of the window clause, or you could use a simple solution of calling the ARRAY_REVERSE function:

```
ARRAY_REVERSE(
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(col1, col2, col3)) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date
    ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
)
```

Added below for the sake of having `reverse the sort order of the window clause` option here

```
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(col1, col2, col3)) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC 
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
```

Comment: You are a god walking among us mere mortals! GREAT JOB!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it helped! (Thanks for adding the alternate example, Mikhail!)